# Insert multiple rows WITHOUT repeating the "INSERT INTO ..." part of the statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, insert

I know I've done this before years ago, but I can't remember the syntax, and I can't find it anywhere due to pulling up tons of help docs and articles about "bulk imports".

Here's what I want to do, but the syntax is not exactly right... please, someone who has done this before, help me out :)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name)
VALUES (123, 'Timmy'),
    (124, 'Jonny'),
    (125, 'Sally')
```

I know that this is *close* to the right syntax. I might need the word "BULK" in there, or something, I can't remember. Any idea?

I need this for a SQL Server 2005 database. I've tried this code, to no avail:

```
DECLARE @blah TABLE
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @blah (ID, Name)
    VALUES (123, 'Timmy')
    VALUES (124, 'Jonny')
    VALUES (125, 'Sally')

SELECT * FROM @blah
```

I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.`

Comment: Your above code is fine just need to add ',' after values statement

Comment: INSERT INTO @blah (ID, Name),
    VALUES (123, 'Timmy'),
    VALUES (124, 'Jonny'),
    VALUES (125, 'Sally')

Comment: Just a caution: you can insert up to 1000 rows only by this method.  INSERT INTO #Test (LWPurchaseOrderID )VALUES   
( 935791 ),
( 935933 )

Comment: 2005 is no longer supported.  For 2008, 2012 and 2016 you can _almost_ use what you put `INSERT INTO @blah (ID, Name)
    VALUES (123, 'Timmy'), (124, 'Jonny'), (125, 'Sally')
`  "VALUES" only appears once and you need commas between the sets.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name)
SELECT 123, 'Timmy'
UNION ALL
SELECT 124, 'Jonny'
UNION ALL
SELECT 125, 'Sally'
```

For SQL Server 2008, can do it in one VALUES clause *exactly* as per the statement in your question (you just need to add a comma to separate each values statement)...

Comment: I think that it's better to write more ugly rather than less effective. I mean unnecessary load of database engine

Comment: Is this any more efficient than using multiple INSERT statements?

Comment: @Code Commander: no, in that it is longer to compile. Yes, in that you have one insert only. But it answers the question: no repeat of the `INSERT table (columnlist)`

Comment: @gbn Thanks for the answer, it seems to be the only way to perform multiple INSERT statements at once in SQL Server CE. I am very curious, though, after reading up on what UNION ALL does, how this actually works, at all. I see the SELECT, the UNION ALL, and of course, the original INSERT INTO statement, but I don't see how this is actually pushing multiple row's values like it is. I am curious because I would like to append UPDATE statements, as well, and wanted to test if this was possible, but before I can do that, I need to understand how this much of it works.

Comment: @VoidKing I know this comes half a year later and you might have figured this out yet long ago, but it's really quite simple. By using `select` you create a set with columns and rows, and by design these rows can be `insert`ed into another table with an equal amount of columns. You can even use a mixture of literals and values. For example, using `insert` with `select 'A', ID from ATable` would insert 'A' in the first column every time and the ID column value of the corresponding row of ATable in the second column.

Comment: This also workes with DB2 which is an important sidenote for those of us stuck in outdated technology. The values seperated by comma answer is better in my mind for those of you working in SQL Server 2008 or newer. The OP can remove all "values" except the first and replace with a ,

Comment: Is this possible with a select statement? I'm trying to avoid explicitly creating a #table (temporary table).

Comment: While this works, it took twice as long to load our current database as multiple values statements.

Comment: @PRMan you would not do that after version SQL Server 2008. As mentioned...

Answer (score 556):

Your syntax almost works in SQL Server 2008 (but not in SQL Server 2005<sup>1</sup>):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (id int, name char(10));

INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Peter'), (3, 'Joe');

SELECT * FROM MyTable;

id |  name
---+---------
1  |  Bob       
2  |  Peter     
3  |  Joe
```

---

<sup>1</sup> When the question was answered, it was not made evident that the question was referring to SQL Server 2005. I am leaving this answer here, since I believe it is still relevant.

Comment: Works in SQL Server 2012

Comment: Server 2008 doesn't allow more than 1000 rows inserted this way.

Comment: What happens, if one value set is faulty? Will all inserts rolled back or just the faulty row?

Comment: @netblognet I just tested that only faulty rows are not inserted (all of the all the others are inserted correctly)

Comment: @Michael It could be lifted https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703601/5070879

Answer (score 253):

If your data is already in your database you can do:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, Name)
SELECT ID, NAME FROM OtherTable
```

If you need to hard code the data then SQL 2008 and later versions let you do the following...

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, ID)
VALUES ('First',1),
('Second',2),
('Third',3),
('Fourth',4),
('Fifth',5)
```

Answer (score 37):

Using `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` syntax like in [Daniel Vassallo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2624750/5070879) answer
there is one annoying limitation:

> From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)
>
> The maximum number of rows that can be constructed by inserting rows directly in the VALUES list is **1000**

The easiest way to omit this limitation is to use derived table like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Mytable(ID, Name)
SELECT ID, Name 
FROM (
   VALUES (1, 'a'),
          (2, 'b'),
          --...
          -- more than 1000 rows
)sub (ID, Name);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/FMWF11820)**</kbd>

---

*This will work starting from SQL Server 2008+*

Comment: Can I have a link to an article about this 'sub' syntax.

Comment: @CodeCamper https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql  section: `C. Specifying multiple values as a derived table in a FROM clause`

Comment: The advantage of this answer is that it provides a way to specify identical values without repeating them (which is what I was looking for). E.g. with a third column that is identical, you wouldn't need to repeat it for a thousand times.

Comment: @VadimBerman Yes, that is good scenario when there is no default defined on table.

Answer (score 18):

This will achieve what you're asking about:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ID, Name)
    VALUES (123, 'Timmy'), 
           (124, 'Jonny'), 
           (125, 'Sally');
```

For future developers, you can also **insert from another table**:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ID, Name)
    SELECT 
         ID, 
         Name 
    FROM table2
```

Or even **from multiple tables**:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column2, column3)
    SELECT 
         t2.column, 
         t3.column
    FROM table2 t2
         INNER JOIN table3 t3
         ON t2.ID = t3.ID
```

Answer (score 14):

You could do this (ugly but it works):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name) 
select * from
(
 select 123, 'Timmy'
  union all
 select 124, 'Jonny' 
  union all
 select 125, 'Sally'
 ...
) x
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a union:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name) 
SELECT ID, Name FROM (
    SELECT 123, 'Timmy'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 124, 'Jonny'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 125, 'Sally'
) AS X (ID, Name)
```

Answer (score 6):

This looks OK for SQL Server 2008.  For SS2005 & earlier, you need to repeat the VALUES statement.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name)  
VALUES (123, 'Timmy')  
VALUES (124, 'Jonny')   
VALUES (125, 'Sally')
```

**EDIT::** My bad. You have to repeat the 'INSERT INTO' for each row in SS2005.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name)  
VALUES (123, 'Timmy')  
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name)  
VALUES (124, 'Jonny')   
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name)  
VALUES (125, 'Sally')
```

Answer (score 6):

It would be easier to use XML in SQL Server to insert multiple rows otherwise it becomes very tedious.

View full article with code explanations here http://www.cyberminds.co.uk/blog/articles/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-in-sql-server.aspx

Copy the following code into sql server to view a sample.

```
declare @test nvarchar(max)

set @test = '<topic><dialog id="1" answerId="41">
        <comment>comment 1</comment>
        </dialog>
    <dialog id="2" answerId="42" >
    <comment>comment 2</comment>
        </dialog>
    <dialog id="3" answerId="43" >
    <comment>comment 3</comment>
        </dialog>
    </topic>'

declare @testxml xml
set @testxml = cast(@test as xml)
declare @answerTemp Table(dialogid int, answerid int, comment varchar(1000))

insert @answerTemp
SELECT  ParamValues.ID.value('@id','int') ,
ParamValues.ID.value('@answerId','int') ,
ParamValues.ID.value('(comment)[1]','VARCHAR(1000)')
FROM @testxml.nodes('topic/dialog') as ParamValues(ID)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
USE YourDB
GO
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
SELECT 'First' ,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' ,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth' ,4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth' ,5
GO
```

### OR YOU CAN USE ANOTHER WAY

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
VALUES 
('First',1),
('Second',2),
('Third',3),
('Fourth',4),
('Fifth',5)
```

Answer (score 6):

I've been using the following:

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] (ID, Name)
values (NEWID(), NEWID())
GO 10
```

It will add ten rows with unique GUIDs for ID and Name.

Note: do not end the last line (GO 10) with ';' because it will throw error: A fatal scripting error occurred. Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing GO.

Answer (score 5):

Corresponding to [INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28SQL.90%29.aspx#ctl00_MTCS_main_ctl58_ctl00_ctl02_) (SQL Server 2005) you can't omit `INSERT INTO dbo.Blah` and have to specify it every time or use another syntax/approach,

Answer (score 4):

In **PostgreSQL**, you can do it as follows;

A generic example for a 2 column table;

```
INSERT INTO <table_name_here>
    (<column_1>, <column_2>)
VALUES
    (<column_1_value>, <column_2_value>),
    (<column_1_value>, <column_2_value>),
    (<column_1_value>, <column_2_value>),
    ...
    (<column_1_value>, <column_2_value>);
```

See the real world example here;

#### A - Create the table

```
CREATE TABLE Worker
(
    id serial primary key,
    code varchar(256) null,
    message text null
);
```

#### B - Insert bulk values

```
INSERT INTO Worker
    (code, message)
VALUES
    ('a1', 'this is the first message'),
    ('a2', 'this is the second message'),
    ('a3', 'this is the third message'),
    ('a4', 'this is the fourth message'),
    ('a5', 'this is the fifth message'),
    ('a6', 'this is the sixth message');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working very fast,and efficient in SQL.
Suppose you have Table `Sample with 4 column a,b,c,d where a,b,d are int and c column is Varchar(50)`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample](
[a] [int] NULL,
[b] [int] NULL,
[c] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[D] [int] NULL
)
```

So you cant inset multiple records in this table using following query without repeating insert statement,

```
DECLARE @LIST VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @LIST='SELECT 1, 1, ''Charan Ghate'',11
     SELECT 2,2, ''Mahesh More'',12
     SELECT 3,3,''Mahesh Nikam'',13
     SELECT 4,4, ''Jay Kadam'',14'
INSERT SAMPLE (a, b, c,d) EXEC(@LIST)
```

Also With C# using `SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con)`

You can insert 10 rows at a time

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("a");
        dt.Columns.Add("b");
        dt.Columns.Add("c");
        dt.Columns.Add("d");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["a"] = 1;
            dr["b"] = 2;
            dr["c"] = "Charan";
            dr["d"] = 4;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String");
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            con.Open();
            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "Sample";
            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Others here have suggested a couple multi-record syntaxes. Expounding upon that, I suggest you insert into a temp table first, and insert your main table from there.

The reason for this is loading the data from a query can take longer, and you may end up locking the table or pages longer than is necessary, which slows down *other* queries running against that table.

```
-- Make a temp table with the needed columns
select top 0 *
into #temp
from MyTable (nolock)

-- load data into it at your leisure (nobody else is waiting for this table or these pages)
insert #temp (ID, Name)
values (123, 'Timmy'),
(124, 'Jonny'),
(125, 'Sally')

-- Now that all the data is in SQL, copy it over to the real table. This runs much faster in most cases.
insert MyTable (ID, Name)
select ID, Name
from #temp

-- cleanup
drop table #temp
```

Also, your IDs should probably be identity(1,1) and you probably shouldn't be inserting them, in the vast majority of circumstances. Let SQL decide that stuff *for* you.

Answer (score 0):

> [Oracle SQL Server Insert Multiple Rows](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm)

In a multitable insert, you insert computed rows derived from the rows returned from the evaluation of a subquery into one or more tables.

**Unconditional INSERT ALL**:- To add multiple rows to a table at once, you use the following form of the INSERT statement:

```sql
INSERT ALL
   INTO table_name (column_list) VALUES (value_list_1)
   INTO table_name (column_list) VALUES (value_list_2)
   INTO table_name (column_list) VALUES (value_list_3)
   ...
   INTO table_name (column_list) VALUES (value_list_n)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL; -- SubQuery
```

[image]

Specify ALL followed by multiple insert_into_clauses to perform an unconditional multitable insert. Oracle Database executes each insert_into_clause once for each row returned by the subquery.

> [MySQL Server Insert Multiple Rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

---

Single Row insert Query

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col1,col2) VALUES(val1,val2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a table to insert multiple records at the same.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST 
(
    id numeric(10,0),
    name varchar(40)
)
```

After that created a stored procedure to insert multiple records.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddMultiple
(
    @category varchar(2500)
)
as
BEGIN

declare @categoryXML xml;
set @categoryXML = cast(@category as xml);

    INSERT INTO TEST(id, name)
    SELECT
        x.v.value('@user','VARCHAR(50)'),
        x.v.value('.','VARCHAR(50)')
    FROM @categoryXML.nodes('/categories/category') x(v)
END
GO
```

Executed the procedure

```
EXEC AddMultiple @category = '<categories> 
                                  <category user="13284">1</category> 
                                  <category user="132">2</category>
                              </categories>';
```

Then checked by query the table.

```
select * from TEST;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using json for the original data and no temp table is needed.

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max) = '[
  {
    "ID": 123,
    "Name": "Timmy"
  },
  {
    "ID": 124,
    "Name": "Jonny"
  },
  {
    "ID": 125,
    "Name": "Sally"
  }
]';


DECLARE @blah TABLE
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @blah (ID, Name)
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (ID int, Name varchar(100))

SELECT * FROM @blah
```