# sqlite insert taking long time

Tags: sql, linux, sqlite, terminal

I'm inserting just short of 200,000 rows into an sqlite database table.  I'm just using a very plain .sql file via sqlite3 in terminal.  I'd bet it's been running for at least 30 minutes.  Is this normal or should I shut the process down and try something differently?

Comment: Insert speeds depend a lot on the table design, like if you have indexes, etc. Why not post your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert speed in sqlite mainly depends on:

- amount of inserts per transaction (insert without transaction is an atomic insert, each in it's own transaction, which means it's very slow)
- database mode - WAL or normal journal
- number of indexes on the inserted fields
- disk speed

If speed is a problem, then you should consult google for each of those factors I wrote and act appropriately.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot.  that's exactly what i'll do as there are some terms there that i've never heard before.

Comment: yes, or course.  Thank you.  I like a take a few moments to follow the answers before voting/accepting them.  Just in case somebody else has similar issues and finds this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing bulk inserts, the kind where you specify the values in a big list, rather than inserting one row at a time.  Like this: [SQL Bulk Insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365992/sql-bulk-insert-statement)