# Insert into SQLite taking a lot of time

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-indexes

I have 2 copies of a SQLite Database. Database 1 has arrived at a state through some failed(Process killed through Task Manager) transactions. Database 2 has not had any failed transactions.
Insert query on Database 1 takes about 200ms while the same query on Database 2 takes 0.5ms.
The two databases have the same indexes.
What are the other factors which could cause a delay in running INSERT query?

Comment: other factors? Do you know any factors now, except how you got into the bad state? Are the two databases identical in other respects (or at least should be), like number of rows and the row data themselves in the tables?

Comment: I read on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787943/sqlite-insert-taking-long-time that there are other factors affecting Insert speed. But i do not know which one to consider, since the databases are basically the same.  Yes, the 2 databases are almost the same when it comes to number of rows and row data. I can see that they are almost the same file size too.

Comment: Trying running VACUUM; in both database and see if that helps.  VACUUM will basically rebuild the database and clear out all the fluff from previous transactions.