# mass insert individual line SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my issues,
I'm provided with a text file with around 900k line that looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (VAL1, Val2, val3)
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (VAL1, Val2, val3)
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (VAL1, Val2, val3)
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (VAL1, Val2, val3)
```

When i run this into SQL server i get an out of memory error.
Is there a way to split this into bulk other than Copy/Paste/Comment 
that would prevent Server to not execute this and prevent lost data because of poor selection during the select/copy/past/comment process that would also take forever!

Comment: Explore this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365992/sql-insert-multiple-rows

Comment: Do you have access to the original table that this data was scripted from?

Comment: I don't have access to the original table.

Comment: how about using a command line sql client?

Comment: "When i run this into SQL server i get an out of memory error." - I am pretty sure you do not. I am pretty sure you get an OOM when trying to run it in SSMS and the OOM is a SSMS error. Why do you not use sqlcmd to run it from a command line?

Comment: You should ask for the file to come in a format that will facilitate bulk loading.  It will run much faster and consume less server resources.  Failing that I would consider a process to find and replace as necessary to get the bulk load ready file.

Comment: Ill to run it from command line and will come back to you.

Comment: I've Done it using SQLcmd and it's going fine, Now i just need to figure out how to  process special character like 'é è' Thank for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to insert the same data over and over you can loop it with `WHILE`. If you are using meaningful data you can try `BULK INSERT` with excel file.

Comment: No the data on each row is not the same.

Comment: Try to add it in excel file and bulk insert it. It will save a lot of time i think.

Answer (score 0):

commit one time / every 5 insert

it looks like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (VAL1, Val2, val3)
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (VAL1, Val2, val3)
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (VAL1, Val2, val3)
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (VAL1, Val2, val3)
commit;
```

if it also throw memory exception then

can you provide how to run it. ex..`use sql server manager studio to run sql script`?

Answer (score 0):

Use Word to do a FIND AND REPLACE on the text file, replacing all instances of **)** with 
**)^lGO^l**  Saving and running the new text file will commit each INSERT statement individually.