# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ',' trying to INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server

i've succesfully created db and tables, but when i try populate one of a table, like this

```
INSERT INTO Products(IsProductActive,ProductName,ProductCount) 
VALUES(0,'productName1',0),
      (0,'productName2',0),
      (1,'productName3',9),
      (1,'productName4',7),
      (1,'productName5',3),
      (1,'productName6',10),
      (0,'productName7',0),
      (1,'productName8',6),
      (1,'productName9',12),
      (1,'productName10',20);
GO
```

i got an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1,
>
> Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ','.

firstly which ',' is meant, secondly - what is wrong?
PS: i use MS Management Studio v 9.0 if it is needed...

Comment: Table Value Constructors; SQL 2008 onward only; http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Versions of SQL Server 2005 and below do not support the multiple VALUE clause syntax

SQL Server 2005 is version 9...

See [How do I insert multiple rows WITHOUT repeating the "INSERT INTO dbo.Blah" part of the statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2624713/27535) for more

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `SQL SERVER 2005` and below, the query wouldn't work because it doesn't support multiple value clause insert statement. You should insert it one by one.

Like this one below,

```
INSERT INTO Products(IsProductActive,ProductName,ProductCount) 
VALUES(0,'productName1',0)
GO
INSERT INTO Products(IsProductActive,ProductName,ProductCount) 
VALUES(0,'productName2',0)
GO
```