# getDateTime from ResultSet java

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, resultset

I have two columns which store DateTime values in a MySql database,

When I try to get them from a ResultSet in Java there is no option: 
`getDateTime()`

Should I use `getDate()` or wouldn't that work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `getDate()` only returns a `Date`, so in your case if you want both date and time use `getTimestamp(String columnLabel)` - That should work, also replace `String columnLabel` with the actual column name in the database.

Comment: `getTimestamp ` is `Timestamp` but the field is `DateTime`, which is throwing compilation error

Comment: Timestamp ts1 = rs.getTimestamp(String columnLabel);   
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(ts1);  
you may have to mess with timezone though if you do that, so check your times.  
 DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(ts1,DateTimeZone.UTC);

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ResultSet.getTimeStamp()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int%29)

Answer (score 4):

### Prefer timestamp over datetime in MySQL

First, if the datetime in your database is to represent a point in time, use the `timestamp` datatype in MySQL for that, not `datetime`. A `datetime` is open for interpretation into any time zone the reader or the program reading it happens to use. This can lead to errors that are hard to debug. The `timestamp` datatype behaves differently in various RDBMSs. In MySQL it makes sure that dates and times are in UTC, thus excluding faulty interpretation into any other time zone. It’s safer. If the dates and times are a little harder for users in your own time zone to read in the database, it’s worth it.

### java.time

```
    PreparedStatement ps = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement("select your_datetime_col from your_table;");
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            OffsetDateTime dateTime = rs.getObject("your_datetime_col", OffsetDateTime.class);
            // do something with dateTime
        }
    }
```

Use `ResultSet.getObject()` for retrieving date and time from the database into a type from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The classes `java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.sql.Date`and `java.util.Date` mentioned or implied in the question and the other answers are all poorly designed and long outdated, so I recommend the modern API instead. It requires a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver. Most of us have that, and one has been out for MySQL for very many years. SO I expect that you are fine.

If you cannot change the datatype in MySQL, use `LocalDateTime` in Java for retrieving values from your `datatime` column. It goes in the same way as in the code above.

### To answer your concrete question

> Should I use `getDate()` or wouldn't that work?

No it would not. `getDate()` gives you a `java.sql.Date` holding only the date part from the database, the time of day part will be missing. As I said, `java.sql.Date` is also poorly designed — a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` — so you shouldn’t want that anyway.

### Links

- [Java Best Practice for Date Manipulation/Storage for Geographically Diverse Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075780/java-best-practice-for-date-manipulation-storage-for-geographically-diverse-user)
- [My answer to Getting the date from a ResultSet for use with java.time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

Or with a typecast from date to string:

`resultSet.getDate(1).toString());`

will return:

`2014-02-18`

DB field data: "2014-02-18 00:00:00.000"

Comment: `getDate()` doesn't give you the `time` part. This is not the best if you want the `time` part of the `mysql datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

> Converting `java.sql.Timestamp` to `java.util.Date`.

```java
java.util.Date date = rs.getDate(index_position); // O/P: DD:MM:YYYY

java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(index_position); // O/P: DD:MM:YYYY HH:mm:ss
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(timestamp.getTime());
```

If you timestamp to date and convert it to `java.sql.Timestamp` then it results to `DD:MM:YYYY 00:00:00` as the date will not cover time. So, it picks default as `00:00:00`.

```
SQL TimeStamp  : 30.12.2020 13.40.50
Java TimeStamp : 30.12.2020 13.40.50

SQL TimeStamp  : 30.12.2020 13.40.50
Java Date      : 30.12.2020 00.00.00
Java TimeStamp : 30.12.2020 00.00.00
```

Example to get records based on [`ResultSetMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) for CSV Report:

```java
public static void getTestTable(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "select ID, INSERTDATE, TO_CHAR(INSERTTIME,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as String_Time, INSERTTIME, MSG from TEST_TABLE group by ID, INSERTDATE, INSERTTIME, MSG";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (rs != null) {
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int noOfColumns = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); // For iteration
        System.out.println("No of Cloumns Query Returns: "+ noOfColumns);
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<?>> matrixTable = getMatrixMetadata(resultSetMetaData);
        System.out.println("MatrixTable: "+matrixTable);
        ArrayList<String> dataTypeList = (ArrayList<String>) matrixTable.get("ColumnTypeName");
        int rowCount = 0;
        while (rs.next()) { // CSV Report
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= noOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
                // int id = rs.getInt("ID");
                String value = getMatrixValue(rs, dataTypeList, columnIndex);
                System.out.print(value);
                if (columnIndex < noOfColumns) {
                    System.out.print(",");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            rowCount++;
        }
        System.out.println("Result FetchSize(Total Columns):"+rs.getFetchSize()+" = Rows*Columns:["+rowCount+"*"+noOfColumns+"]");  
    }
}
static HashMap<String, ArrayList<?>> getMatrixMetadata(ResultSetMetaData meta) throws SQLException {
    int columnsCount = meta.getColumnCount();
    ArrayList<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> dataTypeNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> dataTypeIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<?>> returnHashMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<?>>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnsCount; i++) {
        columnList.add(meta.getColumnName(i));
        dataTypeIdList.add(Integer.valueOf(meta.getColumnType(i)));
        dataTypeNameList.add(meta.getColumnTypeName(i));
    }
    returnHashMap.put("ColumnName", columnList);
    returnHashMap.put("ColumnTypeId", dataTypeIdList);
    returnHashMap.put("ColumnTypeName", dataTypeNameList);
    return returnHashMap;
}
static DecimalFormat DECIMAL_FORMAT = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
static { // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html
    DECIMAL_FORMAT.applyPattern("######.###"); // "#,#00.0#" → 1,234.56 
}
public static String getMatrixValue(ResultSet rs, ArrayList<String> dataTypeNameList, int pos) throws SQLException {
    String retval;
    String columnTypeName = dataTypeNameList.get(pos - 1);
    //int type = dataTypeIdList.get(pos - 1);
    //if (type == Types.DECIMAL || type == Types.DOUBLE || type == Types.FLOAT || type == Types.NUMERIC || type == Types.REAL) {
    if (columnTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("NUMBER")) {
        double doubleValue = rs.getDouble(pos);
        if (rs.wasNull()) {
            retval = null;
        } else {
            retval = "[N]"+DECIMAL_FORMAT.format(doubleValue);
        }
    } else if (columnTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("DATE")) {
        java.util.Date date = rs.getDate(pos);
        if (rs.wasNull()) { // Checks last column read had a value of SQL NULL.
            retval = null;
        } else {
            retval = "[D]"+formatDate(date, "dd.MM.yy");
        }
    } else if (columnTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("TIMESTAMP")) {
        java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(pos);
        if (rs.wasNull()) {
            retval = null;
        } else {
            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(timestamp.getTime());
            retval = "[T]"+formatDate(date, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        }
    } else { // VARCHAR2
        retval = "[S]"+rs.getString(pos);
    }
    return retval;
}
public static String formatDate(Date aDate, String formatStr) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( formatStr );
    //dateFormat.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")));
    return dateFormat.format(aDate);
}
```

```
No of Cloumns Query Returns: 5
MatrixTable: {ColumnName=[ID, INSERTDATE, STRING_TIME, INSERTTIME, MSG], ColumnTypeId=[2, 93, 12, 93, 12], ColumnTypeName=[NUMBER, DATE, VARCHAR2, TIMESTAMP, VARCHAR2]}
[N]1,[D]30.12.20,[S]30.12.2020 00:40:50,[T]30.12.2020 00:40,[S]Insert1
[N]2,[D]30.12.20,[S]30.12.2020 13:40:50,[T]30.12.2020 13:40,[S]Insert2
Result FetchSize(Total Columns):10 = Rows*Columns:[2*5]
```

SQL queries involved are for Table creation and multi record insertion: <sup>[Oracle Multi insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59580311/5081877)</sup>

```sql
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA7.TEST_TABLE 
(
    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "INSERTDATE" DATE, 
    "INSERTTIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "MSG" VARCHAR2(120 BYTE) 
);

INSERT INTO SCHEMA7.TEST_TABLE (ID, INSERTDATE, INSERTTIME, MSG) VALUES ('1', TO_DATE('30-DEC-2020', 'DD-MON-RR'), TO_TIMESTAMP('30-DEC-2020 12.40.50.00 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'), 'Insert1');
INSERT INTO SCHEMA7.TEST_TABLE  (ID, INSERTDATE, INSERTTIME, MSG) VALUES ('2', TO_DATE('30.12.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), TO_TIMESTAMP('30.12.2020 13.40.50','dd.mm.yyyy hh24.mi.ss'), 'Insert2');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```
public static Date getDate(ResultSet rs, int col, Date def)
{
    try
    {
        Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(col, Calendar.getInstance());
        if(!rs.wasNull())
        {
            return  new Date(ts.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return def;
}
```