# How to use java.time classes correctly?

Tags: java, java-time, localdate

I know this may sound awkward after 3 years of software development, but I'm trying to better understand the java.time classes and how to use them to avoid errors and bad practice.

On the first project where I was involved, the java version used was 8, but date values was stored on legacy class java.util.Date

Two years later, new company, new project with java version 17, but still date values are stored into legacy class java.util.Date

The confusion started when I see that there was a DateUtils on the project with methods like:

```
public static String toString_ddMMyyyy_dotted(Date date){
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefualt()).toLocalDateTime();
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy").format(localDateTime);
}

public static Date getBeginOfTheYear(Date date){
    LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefualt()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate beginOfTheYear = localDate.withMonth(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
    return Date.from(beginOfTheYear.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}
```

So my question was, **why not using directly the java.time classes which have a really good APIs instead of converting a variable into LocalDate/LocalDateTime whenever an operation on the Date is required?**

The idea is to refactor the project as soon as possible to store Date/DateTime/Time values into java.time classes.
I started from a simple module, that saves some data into MongoDB.
I applied the following field type conversion:

- Date values into LocalDate
- Date and time values into LocalDateTime

During test I immediately find an issue, a localDateTime variable with **value of 2023-10-07 12:00:00 was saved on MongoDB as 2023-10-07 10:00:00**

First of all, does this happen only when using LocalDateTime, or does it also happen with LocalDate?

What are the best practices to store date/date-time values on entity/document classes? Should I use ZonedDateTime instead of LocalDateTime?

Comment: *"So my question was, why not using directly the java.time classes"* - Legacy - the time, effort and money involved in updating and testing legacy code, not to mention the risk sometimes means that these aspects remain unchanged for many, many years

Comment: *"During test I immediately find an issue, a localDateTime..."* - my first thought is, understand the timezone in which the MangoDB is operating, this could effect how date/time values are handled.  You should, as much as possible save the time zone information or convert the date/time values from/to UTC - when displayed to the user, convert them to `LocalDateTime` (unless you're required to use the saved time zone)

Comment: The point is - the DB should be agnostic - ie it shouldn't be reliant on defining the timezone of the values, instead, define rules on how date/time values should be stored into the DB (ie always UTC) - this way, when values are read from the DB, you will always know the source time zone.  And yes, I've worked for a global security company who refused to provide the time zone information for there events (because it would have cost to much money to update all the software) ... so make a wild guess over what time that event occurred 

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I understand that updating legacy code takes time, effort and money. But when a project starts from java version 8 or higher, I think that legacy code (like java.util.Date) can and should be avoided.

Comment: Remember, the original developers were probably in the same boat you are right now, trying to better understand a brand new API - they may have chosen to continue with the "old" APIs because they were more familiar with them and or the tools/libraries they had only supported them - just because they wrote their code in Java 8, doesn't mean all the code they had available was written for Java 8 - but that's speculation. Now days, `java.util.Date` and related classes should be considered deprecated and should be avoided, but we now have many years of developer experience to call upon

Comment: *"What are the best practices to store date/date-time values on entity/document classes? Should I use ZonedDateTime instead of LocalDateTime?"* - this is just my opinion, but I would say, yes, make use of `ZonedDateTime` for storing the date/time values where possible - this is not a hard and fast rule, but an over arching general recommendation. Consider the fact that the timezone in which database systems runs in will effect how they handle time information without time zones.  Better to define a simple rule - eg: "all time is converted to UTC before insertion, with time zone information"

Comment: "Best practice" would include not using `java.util.Date` at all ...

Comment: *I know this may sound awkward after 3 years of software development, ...* To me it does not sound awkward at all. Correct date and time handling is complicated and takes time to learn.

Comment: Think twice before using `LocalDateTime` for date and time. If your date and time is supposed to represent a point in time and not in the future, you will probably prefer `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` (the last since it works well with `timestamp with time zone` in SQL databases). A `LocalDateTime` *does not* define a point in time. Even if your software will only be used in one time zone ever, a `LocalDateTime` is ambiguous during fall back (where summer time ends).

Comment: A related good read: [Java Best Practice for Date Manipulation/Storage for Geographically Diverse Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075780/java-best-practice-for-date-manipulation-storage-for-geographically-diverse-user)

Comment: I should also point out that the term "best practice" is false advertising.  See https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Conversion rather than revamp

> The idea is to refactor the project as soon as possible to store Date/DateTime/Time values into java.time classes

Depending on the size and complexity of your codebase, this may be quite risky.

A more conservative approach is to do all new programming in *java.time*. To interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. You will find new conversion methods on the old classes. Look for `to…` & `from…` methods. These conversion methods provide complete coverage, allowing you to go back and forth.

Another word of caution when revamping code: Many/most programmers have a poor understanding of date-time handling. The topic is surprisingly tricky and complicated, the concepts slippery when first encountered. Our quotidian understanding of date-time actually works against us when dealing with the strictness of programming and databases. So beware of poor code, buggy code, that mishandles date-time. Each time you discover such faulty code, you will be opening up a barrel of trouble as reports may have been produced showing incorrect results, databases may store invalid data, etc.

You can search existing Stack Overflow questions and answers to learn more. Below are a few brief points to help guide you.

## Moment versus Not-a-moment

> Date values into LocalDate
>
> Date and time values into LocalDateTime

Incorrect. Or incomplete, I should say.

I recommend you frame your thinking this way… There are two kinds of time tracking:

- Moment (definite)
- Not a moment (indefinite)

### Moment

A moment is a specific point on the timeline. Moments are tracked in *java.time* as a count of whole seconds, plus a fractional second as a count of nanoseconds, since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC. "in UTC" is short for "an offset from the temporal meridian of UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds".

The basic class for representing a moment is `java.time.Instant`. Objects of this class represent a moment as seen in UTC, always in UTC. This class is the basic building-block of the *jav.time* framework. This class should be your first and last thought when dealing with moments. Use `Instant` to track a moment unless your business rules specifically involve a particular zone or offset. And `java.util.Date` is specifically replaced by `java.time.Instant`, with both representing a moment in UTC but with `Instant` having a finer resolution of nanoseconds over the `java.util.Date` resolution of milliseconds.

Two other classes track moments in *java.time*: `OffsetDateTime` & `ZonedDateTime`.

`OffsetDateTime` represents a moment as seen with an offset-from-UTC other than zero. An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind UTC. So people in Paris set the clocks on their wall one or two hours ahead of UTC, while people in Tokyo set their clocks nine hours ahead, whereas people in Nova Scotia Canada set their clocks three or four hours *behind* UTC.

A time zone is much more than a mere offset. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians. A time zone has a name in the format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/Paris` & `Asia/Tokyo`.

To view a date and time-of-day through the wall-clock time of a particular region, use `ZonedDateTime`.

Note that you can easily and cleanly move back and forth between these three classes, `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` via their `to…`, `at…`, and `with…`methods. They provide three ways of looking at the very same moment. Generally you use `Instant` in your business logic and data storage and data exchange, while using `ZonedDateTime` for presentation to the user.

### Not-a-moment

On the other hand, we have "not a moment" tracking. These are the indefinite types.

The not-a-moment class causing the most confusion is `LocalDateTime`. This class represents a date with a time-of-day but lacking any concept of offset or time zone. So if I say noon next January 23rd 2024, `LocalDateTime.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 , 12 , 0 , 0 , 0 )`, you have no way of knowing if I mean noon in Tokyo, noon in Toulouse, or noon in Toledo Ohio US — three very different moments several hours apart.

When in doubt, do *not* use `LocalDateTime`. Generally in programming business apps we care about moments, and so rarely use `LocalDateTime`.

The big exception, when we most often need `LocalDateTime` in business apps, is booking appointments, such as for the dentist. There we need to hold a `LocalDateTime` and time zone (`ZoneId`) *separately* rather than combining them into a `ZonedDateTime`. The reason is crucial: ***Politicians frequently change time zone rules***, and they do so unpredictably and often with little forewarning. So that dentist appoint at 3 PM may occur an hour earlier, or an hour later, if the politicians there decide:

- To adopt Daylight Saving Time (DST).
- To abandon DST.
- To stay on DST year-round (the latest fad).
- That a different offset would bring business opportunities. Example: Iceland adopting an offset of zero.
- That a different offset would have political effects. Example: India instituting one single time zone across the broad sub-continent.
- To adjust their clock as a diplomatic move relative to a neighboring country. Example: North Korea changing their offset to match South Korea.
- To adopt the offset of an invading/occupying force.

All of these happen much more often than most people realize. Such changes break naïvely-written apps needlessly.

The other indefinite types include:

- `LocalDate` for a date-only value without a time-of-day and without any zone/offset.
- `LocalTime` for a time-only value without any date and without any zone/offset.

The `LocalDate` can be tricky in that many people are unaware that, for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. Right now is "tomorrow" in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously "yesterday" in Edmonton Canada.

## Your code

```java
LocalDateTime localDateTime = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefualt()).toLocalDateTime();
```

That code has two problems.

- One is the inappropriate use of `LocalDateTime`. The `java.util.Date` class behind `date` var represents a moment with an offset of zero. You discard the crucial piece of information, the offset, when converting to `LocalDateTime`.
- Another problem is the use of `ZoneId.systemDefualt()`. This means the results vary depending on the JVM’s current default time zone. As discussed above, this means the date may vary, not just the time-of-day. The same code running on two different machines may produce two different dates. This may be what you want in your app, or this may be a rude awakening to an unaware programmer.

Your other piece of code also has problems.

```java
public static Date getBeginOfTheYear(Date date){
    LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefualt()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate beginOfTheYear = localDate.withMonth(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
    return Date.from(beginOfTheYear.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}
```

First of all, be aware there are unfortunately *two* `Date` classes amongst the legacy date-time classes: `java.util.Date` for a moment, and `java.sql.Date` that pretends to represent a date-only but is actually a moment (in a horrendously poor class-design decision). I will assume your means `java.util.Date`.

Secondly, avoid these kinds of call-chains with this kind of code. Readability, debugging, and logging are all made more difficult. Write simple short lines instead when doing a series of conversions. Use comments on each line to justify the operation, and explain your motivation. And, avoid the use of `var` for the same reason; use explicit return types when doing such conversions.

The `date.toInstant()` is good. When encountering a `java.util.Date`, immediately convert to a `Instant`.

Again, the use of `ZoneId.systemDefualt()` means the results of your code vary by the whim of any sys-admin or user who is changing the default time zone. This *might* be the intent of the author of this code, but I doubt it.

The part [`beginOfTheYear.atStartOfDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay()) produces a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) when you pass no arguments. So you are again discarding valuable info (offset) without gaining anything in return.

Another problem: Your code will not even compile. The `java.util.Date.from` method takes an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#from(java.time.Instant)), not a `LocalDateTime` returned by your call [`beginOfTheYear.atStartOfDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay()).

To correctly get the first moment of the first of the year of a particular moment, you almost certainly would want the people deciding business rules to dictate a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
```

You should indeed convert the incoming `java.util.Date` to a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Then apply the zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zTokyo ) ;
```

Extract year portion. As discussed above, the date may vary by time zone. Therefore, the *year may vary* depending on the zone you provided in the previous line of code above!

```
Year year = Year.from( zdt ) ;
```

Get first day of that year.

```
LocalDate firstOfYear = year.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

Let *java.time* determine the first moment of that day in that zone. Do *not* assume the start time is 00:00. Some dates in some zones start at another time such as 01:00.

Notice that in determining the first moment of the year, we pass the argument for `ZoneId` to `atStartOfDay`, in contrast to your code. The result here is a `ZonedDateTime` rather than the `LocalDateTime` in your code.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtFirstMomentOfTheYearInTokyo = firstOfYear.atStartOfDay( zTokyo ) ;
```

Lastly, we convert to `java.util.Date`. In [greenfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenfield_project) code, we would avoid this class like the Plague. But in your existing codebase, we must convert to interoperate with the parts of your old code not yet updated to *java.time*.

```
Instant instantFirstMomentOfTheYearInTokyo = zdtFirstMomentOfTheYearInTokyo.toInstant(); 
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instantFirstMomentOfTheYearInTokyo ) ;
```

## MongoDB

You said:

> During test I immediately find an issue, a localDateTime variable with value of 2023-10-07 12:00:00 was saved on MongoDB as 2023-10-07 10:00:00 This is not a problem as long as when the data is fetched back into java, the value is back to 2023-10-07 12:00:00, but this is not happening so it is a big problem.

Too much to unpack there, with too little detail from you.

I suggest you post another Question specifically on that issue. Provide sufficient detail, along with example code, to make a diagnosis.

Comment: Do you have any example of zone that starts at 1:00 ?

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan This year, time zones in Cuba, Egypt, Lebanon, Paraguay. See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country).