# ColdFusion: How to insert a list with a static foreign key in one insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I have a list like this thing1,thing2,thing3. And I want to insert them into a look-up table with the same foreign key. So ideally it would look like this:

```
<cfquery datasource="#ds#" result="insert_things">
    INSERT INTO lkp_things (foreign_key, thing) VALUES
    (1, thing1), (1, thing2), (1, thing3)
</cfquery>
```

**It seems like the only way to accomplish this is to turn the list into a query, but I'm wondering, is there is a simpler way?**

Here's what I've tried:

```
<cfquery datasource="#ds#" result="insert_things">
    INSERT INTO lkp_things (foreign_key, thing) VALUES
    <cfloop list="#things#" index="thing">
        (#id#,#thing#)<cfif ?????? NEQ len(#things#)>,</cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

I've heard that you can't do a cfloop inside a cfquery, but I'm not even sure if that's true because I can't have a trailing comma in the VALUES, and I'm not sure how to say "The current iteration number" inside a cfloop. If I turned the list into a query, then I could do currentRow, but again, I'd like to know if there's a simpler way to accomplish this before I go through all that.

Also, I'm using CF 8 and sql server '08 EDIT: Sorry, I'm actually using 2000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Ultimately the real problem here was that the feature of inserting multiple sets of values with a single `VALUES` clause is only supported in SQL Server 2008+ and the OP is using 2000. So they went with the [select / union all approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19596550/104223) instead.

---

(Expanded from the comments)

Sure you can loop inside a `cfquery`. All cfml code is processed on the CF server first. Then the resulting SQL string is sent to the database for execution. As long as your CF code results in a valid SQL statement, you can do just about anything you want :) Whether you should is a different question, but this kind of looping is perfectly fine.

Getting back to your question, just switch to a `from/to` loop instead and use list functions like `getToken(list, index)` to get the individual elements (see [Matt's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19592020/104223)) or use an array instead. Obviously you should also validate the list is not empty first.  My personal preference is arrays. Not tested, but something like this:

```
    <cfset thingArray = listToArray(things, ",")>

    <cfquery datasource="#ds#" result="insert_things">
       INSERT INTO lkp_things (foreign_key, thing) VALUES
       <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(thingArray)#" index="x">
           <cfif x gt 1>,</cfif>
           ( 
              <!--- Note: Replace cfsqltype="..." with correct type --->
               <cfqueryparam value="#id#" cfsqltype="..."> 
             , <cfqueryparam value="#thingArray[x]#" cfsqltype="..."> 
           )
       </cfloop>
    </cfquery>
```

Having said that, what is the source of your `#thing#` list? If those values exist in a database table, you could insert them directly with a `SELECT` statement, instead of a loop:

```
       INSERT INTO lkp_things (foreign_key, thing) 
       SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#id#" cfsqltype="...">, thing
       FROM   ThingTable
       WHERE  thing IN 
              (
                <cfqueryparam value="#thingList#" list="true" cfsqltype="..."> 
              )
```

Comment: +1 for using the `list` attribute of the `cfqueryparam` tag (and of course your detail). No looping necessary...

Comment: Well I do not know if it applies here or not :) But the loop-free `insert/select` technique is a simple approach a lot of people overlook, so I figured I would mention it just in case.

Comment: I don't even think the `SELECT` is necessary in this case. The OP mentioned that the `id` does not change and simply using `cfqueryparam` with the `list` attribute should work.

Comment: I am not sure that would work to generate the proper pairs of values. Did you try it out? (I cannot test it right now). Though fyi, I specifically wanted to use a `SELECT` here. Aside from generating the correct values, it also acts as a bit of server side validation. Invalid values that are not in the db table are deliberately ignored.

Comment: No I did not try it out and you are correct about not generating the pairs of values correctly. Guess I didn't think that through completely. Anyway your answer should do the trick if the things are coming from a table.

Comment: The list is not coming from a database, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well it may come in handy in the future :)

Comment: This didn't work for some reason. SQL Server didn't like it. I had to use a SELECT / UNION ALL solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part

Comment: @TravisHeeter - No, it definitely works. I have used the approach many times. Though as I mentioned above, the example is not tested. I am not near a CF install. Update your question with the code that "didn't work" (and any error messages) and I can help you spot the problem.

Comment: @Leigh was getting this error: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Line 2: Incorrect syntax near ','. With this: INSERT INTO lkp_Things (foreign_key,thing) 
VALUES (1,'thing1'),(1,'thing2') I tried a million different ways, nothing worked.

Comment: Two possible causes: 1) I just noticed a typo. I missed the closing quote after the value and before the cfsqltype and 2) Did you remember to fill in your cfsqltypes? Since I do not know your data types, I marked it with the placeholder "..."

Comment: I ran the resulting query in the database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40012/discussion-between-leigh-and-travis-heeter)

Answer (score 2):

I would add a counter and increment it inside the loop. Also you need to use `listLen()` rather than `len` on your list to get the number of items.

```
<cfquery datasource="#ds#" result="insert_things">
  INSERT INTO lkp_things (foreign_key, thing) VALUES
  <cfset count = 1>
  <cfloop list="#things#" index="thing">
    (
     <cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_integer" value="#id#">,
     <cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_varchar" value="#thing#">
    )<cfif count NEQ listLen(things)>,</cfif>
   <cfset count++>
  </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

You should use `cfqueryparam` on all your values. I've guessed on what type the column is.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a database error with

```
INSERT INTO lkp_things (foreign_key,thing) 
VALUES (1,'thing1'),(1,'thing2')
```

Leigh helped me realize that I was actually using SQL Server '00, and that version does not allow this method of insertion. So, I had to use this:

```
INSERT INTO lkp_things (foreign_key,thing)
SELECT 1,'thing1'
    UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'thing2'
```

In CF that looks like this:

```
<cfset thingArray = listToArray(form.things,",")>
<cfquery datasource="aliaba_jdbc" name="insert_courses">
    INSERT INTO lkp_Things (id,thing)
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(thingArray)#" index="x">
        SELECT <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#form.id#">,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#thingArray[x]#">
        <cfif x lt arrayLen(thingArray)>UNION ALL</cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

I found this solution here: [How do I insert multiple rows WITHOUT repeating the "INSERT INTO dbo.Blah" part of the statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part)

Comment: Just as an FYI for future searchers, the ability to insert multiple sets of values with a *single* `VALUES` clause requires SQL Server 2008+.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to Matt's but does not use conditional logic.

```
<cfquery>
insert into lkp_things (foreign_key, thing)
select 0, ''
where 1=2
<cfloop list="#things#" index="thing">
union
select <cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_integer" value="#id#">
, <cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_varchar" value="#thing#">
</cfloop>
```

Both our answers assume that the id variable does not change and was set somewhere else.