# Inserting Multiple Rows in Sybase ASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sybase

(Similar question related to SQL Server : [**SO Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part))

I know in Sql Server 2008 or above, you can insert multiple rows doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, ID)
VALUES ('First',1), ('Second',2), ('Third',3)
```

However, it seems like this syntax DOES NOT work in Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise, since this gives me an error..

Anyone know the syntax in Sybase that achieves the same thing?

Sybase ASE is based on Transact SQL..

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Sybase doen't have insert syntax as SQL Server. What's wrong with showed below classic method?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, ID) VALUES ('First',1)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, ID) VALUES ('Second',2)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, ID) VALUES ('Third',3)
go
```

Comment: What's "wrong", or better inconvenient, is that you have to keep repeating `INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, ID) VALUES`

Comment: @Joel What is your Sybase version?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, ID)
Select 'First',1
Union All 
Select 'Second',2
Union All
Select 'Third',3
```

I know this works on older versions of SQL server, and suspect that it will work with sybase.

Comment: this works, also, it works with parameterized values:  ...select ?,? union all...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like that syntax is not valid in Sybase ASE but as suggested in the linked SO post you can get the same using `UNION ALL` like

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, ID)
SELECT 'First',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third',3
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in SQL Server for this example will not work in Sybase. Either go with individual statements, or UNION ALL clause