# ColdFusion function returns an error "The system has attempted to use an undefined value"?

Tags: coldfusion, sybase, coldfusion-11, cfquery

I have function that should save some form fields. This function is able to process multiple insert rows. So far I was able to create logic to handle this but the only issue so far I have once user tries to save the record. The server response looks like this:

```
The system has attempted to use an undefined value, which usually indicates a programming error, either in your code or some system code. Null Pointers are another name for undefined values. coldfusion
```

At first I was looking and trying to find which value is not defined/missing in my function but so far I couldn't detect the issue. The next thing I did was commenting out the `cfquery`. After that I was getting message `Form successfully saved.`. This tells me that my code is breaking inside of the `cfquery` tag. Here is example of my code:

```
<cffunction name="saveRecords" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="formID" type="string" required="true" default="">
    <cfargument name="status1" type="string" required="true" default="0">
    <cfargument name="status2" type="string" required="true" default="0">
    <cfargument name="status3" type="string" required="true" default="0">
    <cfargument name="status4" type="string" required="true" default="0">
    <cfargument name="status5" type="string" required="true" default="0">
    <cfargument name="comment1" type="string" required="true" default="">
    <cfargument name="comment2" type="string" required="true" default="">
    <cfargument name="comment3" type="string" required="true" default="">
    <cfargument name="comment4" type="string" required="true" default="">
    <cfargument name="comment5" type="string" required="true" default="">

    <cfset local.fnResults = structNew() />
    <cfset local.runProcess = true />
    <cfset local.arrStatus = arrayNew(1) />

    <cfloop collection="#arguments#" item="i">
        <cfif findNoCase(left(i,6), "status") and arguments[i] eq 1>
            <cfset arrayAppend(local.arrStatus, right(i,1)) />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfset local.frmValidation = {
        formID : len(arguments.formID),
        status1 : ArrayContains([0,1], trim(arguments.status1)),
        status2 : ArrayContains([0,1], trim(arguments.status2)),
        status3 : ArrayContains([0,1], trim(arguments.status3)),
        status4 : ArrayContains([0,1], trim(arguments.status4)),
        status5 : ArrayContains([0,1], trim(arguments.status5))
    }/>

    <cfloop collection="#frmValidation#" item="i">
        <cfif !frmValidation[i] or !arrayLen(arrStatus)>
            <cfset local.runProcess = false />
            <cfset local.fnResults = {status: 400, message: "Form data is either missing or incorrect."}>
            <cfbreak>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfif runProcess>
        <!---
        <cfquery name="saveRec" datasource="testDB">
            <cfloop array="#arrStatus#" index="i">
                INSERT INTO formDetails (
                    formid,
                    refid,
                    status,
                    comment,
                    userid,
                    lastupdate
                )
                SELECT
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#trim(arguments.formID)#">,
                    #i#,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="#trim(arguments["status"&i])#">,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="8000" value="#trim(arguments["comment"&i])#" null="#!len(trim(arguments["comment"&i]))#">,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="6" value="#trim(session.userid)#" null="#!len(trim(session.userid))#">,
                    #now()#
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT refid
                    FROM formDetails
                    WHERE formid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#trim(arguments.formID)#">
                        AND refid = #i#
                )
            </cfloop>
        </cfquery>
        --->
        <cfset local.fnResults = {status: 200, message: "Form successfully saved!"}>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn fnResults>
</cffunction>
```

One thing that I forgot to mention is that before I commented out cfquery, I tried to save the records and error will occur that I mentioned above but at the same time record is saved in database. That is weird since I didn't expect query to execute successfully because of the error. I use Sybase database and here are the details about `formDetails` table:

```
column name    data type   length
recid          numeric      18      PK
formid         numeric      10      FK
refid          numeric      18      FK
status         bit          1
comment        varchar      8000
userid         varchar      6
lastupdate     datetime     23
```

I'm not sure where my code is breaking and why I'm getting an error message about `undefined value`. If anyone can help or provide some useful resource on how to fix this issue please let me know.

**UPDATE**

I have been looking for solution on how to fix this problem and I tried using cfscript with `UNION ALL`. This was suggested from few people and here is example of my code:

```
remote function saveRecords(required string formID, string status1="0", string status2="0", string status3="0", string status4="0", string status5="0", string comment1="", string comment2="", string comment3="", string comment4="", string comment5="") output=false returnFormat="JSON" {
        local.fnResults = structNew();
        local.runProcess = true;
        local.arrReference = arrayNew(1);

        try {
            local.frmValidation = {
                formID : len(arguments.formID),
                status1 : ArrayContains([0,1], arguments.status1),
                status2 : ArrayContains([0,1], arguments.status2),
                status3 : ArrayContains([0,1], arguments.status3),
                status4 : ArrayContains([0,1], arguments.status4),
                status5 : ArrayContains([0,1], arguments.status5)
            };

            for ( i in frmValidation ) {
                if ( !frmValidation[i] ) {
                    local.runProcess = false;
                    local.fnResults = {status: 400, message: "Form data is either missing or incorrect."};
                    break;
                }
            }

            for ( fld in arguments ) {
                if ( findNoCase(left(fld,6), "status") && arguments[fld] == 1 ) {
                    arrayAppend(arrReference, right(fld,1));
                }
            }

            if ( runProcess ) {
                local.qrySql = "INSERT INTO formDetails(recid, formid, refid, status, comment, userid, lastupdate)";
                local.qryParams = [];

                for ( idx=1 ; idx<=arraylen(arrReference) ; idx++ ) {
                    local.referenceID = arrReference[idx];
                    local.recPK = trim(arguments.formID) & trim(referenceID);
                    local.statusVal = trim(arguments["status" & local.referenceID]);
                    local.commentVal = trim(arguments["comment" & local.referenceID]);

                    if ( idx != 1 ) {
                        local.qrySql &= " UNION ALL ";
                    }

                    local.qrySql &= " SELECT ?,?,?,?,?,?,?";
                    qryParams.append({cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric", value=local.recPK});
                    qryParams.append({cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric", value=trim(arguments.formID)});
                    qryParams.append({cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric", value=local.referenceID});
                    qryParams.append({cfsqltype="cf_sql_tinyint", value=local.statusVal});
                    qryParams.append({cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar", value=local.commentVal, maxlength=8000, null=!len(local.commentVal)});
                    qryParams.append({cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar", value=trim(session.userid), maxlength=6, null=!len(trim(session.userid))});
                    qryParams.append({cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp", value=now()});
                }

                local.qryResult = queryExecute(qrySQL, qryParams, {datasource="#application.datasource#", result="insertRecords"});

                local.fnResults = {result: insertRecords, sql: qrySql, params: qryParams, array: arrReference, args: arguments, status: 200, message: "Form successfully saved!"};
            }
        } catch (any e) {
            local.fnResults = {sql: qrySql, params: qryParams, error: e, status: 400, message: "Error! Something went wrong..."};
        }

        return fnResults;
    }
```

After I tried to save the record from I got the message `Something went wrong...`. I looked in response and all I can see is error that is pointing to the this line:

```
local.qryResult = queryExecute(qrySQL, qryParams, {datasource="#application.datasource#", result="insertRecords"});
```

I checked the database and records are in there. No details about this error nothing. At least I'm not getting an error that I described in the question above but still no clue what is causing my code to crash.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188841/discussion-on-question-by-espresso-coffee-coldfusion-function-returns-an-error).

Comment: I did find the problem why my code is not working. I removed all `cfqueryparams` in my code and everything worked just fine. So there is a problem in cfsql_types that are supported in Sybase database. I do not know much about sybase and this issue. If anyone have any articles or suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two things 
1) you insert query does not have any value. INSERT INTO tablename( columns ... )   VALUES ( column values.. ) But you have missed VALUE key word in your query. 
2) Whenever you are going to do two query operations in single cfquery tag you should add some Connection String  in your testDB data sources. Which is available in CFML admin part. Open you data source and set below options. In CFML admin :
  [image]

If you are using Lucee means: Please check the below options in your data source which is available in lucee server / web admin,

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct since I'm using Sybase database. Here is the link where you can find example on the correct syntax for multiple row insert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635327/inserting-multiple-rows-in-sybase-ase The sql code in my example is valid and works since I tested multiple times. Even when my code produce the error that i explained record is being inserted in database. The only issue is that my code is returning error but can't find the issue in my code.

Comment: Huh!. What I meant here, As per my knowledge if you are using two query which mean you are using INSERT & SELECT with in same cfquery tag. So that I suggested that way. Let me think again what was the issue in your code. And may I know what about VALUES ? You have missed that in INSERT query.

Comment: You don't need a `VALUE` in your `INSERT` if you `INSERT....SELECT`. The `SELECT` statement replaces the `VALUE`.