# Sybase interacting with mybatis

Tags: syntax-error, sap-ase, spring-mybatis

Im unable to insert multiple records in a single transaction. Im using `foreach in mapper` and I'm getting `incorrect syntax near ','`.
I googled and found, in sybase it's not possible to insert multiple rows in sybase.

Insert statement looks like:

```sql
insert into Student(id,name)
values (1, Jon), (2,mike),(3,sam)
```

Comma next to value statement, is creating issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting Multiple Rows in Sybase ASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635327/inserting-multiple-rows-in-sybase-ase)

Comment: Yes, the question is similar to above post. I didn't see appropriate answer. I want to achieve multiple inserts in one transaction in sybase ase

Comment: You can't insert multiple rows in Sybase ASE by using `values`. Only if you already have the data in a table and inserting with `select`. A possible "hack" would be to use `union all`. For instance `insert into Student(id, name) select 1, "Jon" union all select 2, "Mike" union all select 3, "Sam"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im using mybatis for persistence  and I want to use foreach to insert multiple values in single transaction.