# Inserting muliple values into database

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to insert multiple records into the database at a single button click. I have a textbox, and when the user enters 3 into the textbox, 3 rows should be inserted into the database. How should I do this. Please help out. Thank you.

Comment: Please help, I really want to do it but dont know how.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part). Doesnt this help?  @user2782692

Comment: You can't just tell us that you don't know how to do. You have to show the code you already have. This is not a gimme-my-code service.

Comment: 3 rows with what data??Please post the target database table and elaborate more your required input and output..

Comment: which database you are using??

Comment: ok I will provide a snapshot of what i am doing:

Comment: I have a textbox and a hidden field for random number generation. When the user enters an number in the textbox and clicks the save button, that many records are generated and saved in the database. I am sorry but I am unable to display the snapshot

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL only it is possible with somthing like this:-

```
INSERT INTO TAB_NAME(COL1, COL2) 
VALUES(VALUE1, VALUE2), 
      (VALUE1, VALUE2), 
      (VALUE1, VALUE2), 
      (VALUE1, VALUE2), 
      (VALUE1, VALUE2);
```

Above command will insert 5 ros to databse at a time simultaneously.