# Insert multiple values into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I'm kind of new in using SQL Server and I have this problem. I don't know how do I have to concatenate in order to insert into one column table multiple values.

```
INSERT INTO Table (Column) 
VALUES ('Name'+','+' Last name',);,('Name'+','+'Last name',);
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert multiple rows WITHOUT repeating the "INSERT INTO dbo.Blah" part of the statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table (Column) 
VALUES ('Name'+','+ 'Last name')  --<-- no comma required inside the paranthesis
      ,('Name'+','+ 'Last name');  --<-- only need semi-colon here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use should use || symbols for concatenate.
Example: `SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name   FROM hr.employees;`

Comment: this is for sql server. you cannot concatenate using `||`