# Creating temporary table with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, console-application, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure which is returning few columns (now this stored procedure is being managed by other teams so they can add further columns in it)

```
ALTER SP MyCallingSP
AS
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 
    FROM Table
END
```

I am calling this stored procedure from my C# code in which I am inserting the result set into a data table.

Now, I have to create a global temporary table from this datatable.
Problem is, tomorrow they can add a new column in it and then it might fail my process.

From the above example, I just need col1, col2, col3 which I want to insert into a global temporary table.

I am able to get the data into datatable but I am not sure about how to proceed further.

Comment: Why would it fail your process? Just use the columns you need in the data table

Comment: I have filled datatable using data adapter. So, my datatable has all 4 columns. So, how can I now create temp table for only 3 columns out if it?

Comment: Why do you want to, why do you care how many columns are in the datatable? WHat process do you have that actually cares what extra columns there are?

Comment: I am feeling dumb now :( I don't know what to say. Are you saying I can insert only required columns from datatable to temporary table? Or please correct me if I my understanding is wrong

Comment: Start at the beginning: what are you trying to *do*, what is the global temp table for? And have you considered using `SqlBulkCopy` to insert the columns you need?

Comment: I have insert the results from the stored procedure into a global temporary table. So, right now SP has 3 columns so I can manually loop datatable which got filled from the SP and loop through it.  write CREATE ##MyTable TABLE with column name.

Comment: I am checking bulkcopy now, thanks for the suggestion. Is this code is doing the same? Calling SP and then dumping only required columns to temp table? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839404/select-into-temptable-from-c-sharp-datatable

Comment: You need to add `ColumnMapping`s and that code is also missing `using` statements