# How to insert multiple child rows in just one click

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I created two table parent and child.

Cus: Parent

```
+----+-------------------------+------+
| ID |          Name           | Age  |
+----+-------------------------+------+
|  1 | Japhet                  | 22   |
|  2 | Abegail                 | 31   |
|  3 | Norlee                  | 35   |
|  4 | Pacita                  | 60   |
|  5 | Reynaldo                | 65   |
|  6 | Barro, Reynaldo Batucan | 65   |
|  7 | Batucan, Japhet C.      | NULL |
|  8 | Barro, Reynaldo B.      | NULL |
+----+-------------------------+------+
```

Cus2: Child

```
+-----+----+------+---------+
| QID | ID | Name | Country |
+-----+----+------+---------+
|     |    |      |         |
+-----+----+------+---------+
```

I've used the codes below to populate the datagridview with the custom rows, but when I attempt to save it, it won't save. I get this error message:

> Input string was not in correct format. Couldn't store  in ID Column. Expected type is Int32.

Also, the Cus.ID will not populate in Cus2.ID

```
Private Sub Populate()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(3) {New DataColumn("QID", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Country", GetType(String))})
        Try
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 0, "John Hammond", "United States")
            dt.Rows.Add(2, 0, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
            dt.Rows.Add(3, 0, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
            dt.Rows.Add(4, 0, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")

            Me.Cus2DataGridView.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Populate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Cus2DataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Cus2DataGridView.CellContentClick

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Cus2DataGridView.Rows
            Dim constring As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-0M1930H\PNJK;Initial Catalog=Hello;Integrated Security=True"
            Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Cus2 VALUES(@QID, @ID, @Name, @Country)", con)
                    Try
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QID", row.Cells("QID").Value)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells("ID").Value)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", row.Cells("Name").Value)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", row.Cells("Country").Value)
                        con.Open()
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        con.Close()
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        Next
    End Sub
```

I am new to this, so please help. Thanks :D

Comment: My general advice: Do away with the comma separated representation of parent-child relationships.  Instead, have one column with a parent and one column with a child.

Comment: "when I attempt to save it, it won't save". What does that actually mean?  EXACTLY what actually happens?

Comment: @jmcilhinney some pop-up will show: http://prntscr.com/brr4g5

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, but I don't understand what it is saying. Still new to this.

Comment: Specify the column names in the SQL - you are assuming the DB has the columns in the same exact order as you are specifying the values in - it apparently does not.  see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/  You could also insert all the rows on the same connection, and same command object

Comment: Assuming you are using sql server 2008 or later (and you should), you should use a [table valued parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965233/adding-multiple-parameterized-variables-to-a-database-in-c-sharp/31965525#31965525) instead of inserting records one by one.