# How to insert 2 rows from one INSERT statement?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a shopping cart that displays the different products the customer has selected to purchase. I need to INSERT each product selected as a single row with the same customer_id in the 'order_details' table.

**Screenshot**
[image: The database]

**code**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect to database");
    @mysql_select_db("bookstore") or die("Could not select database");
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bookstore');
    include("admin/php/myFunctions.php");
    $customer = $_SESSION['id_login'];
    $order = $_SESSION['id_login'];

    if(!empty($_GET['prodid'])){
        $pid = $_GET['prodid'];
        $wasFound = false;
        $i = 0;
        if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
            $_SESSION["cart_array"]=array(0=>array("productID"=>$pid,"quantity"=>1));
        }else{
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_product){
                $i++;
                while(list($key,$value)=each($each_product)){
                    if($key=="productID" && $value==$pid){  
                        array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"],$i-1,1,array(array("productID"=>$pid,"quantity"=>$each_product ['quantity']+1)));
                        $wasFound=true;
                    }
                }       
            }
            if($wasFound==false){
                array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"],array("productID"=>$pid,"quantity"=>1));
            }
        }
        header("location:shoppingcart.php");
        exit();
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @$submit = $_POST['btnUpdate'];
    if($submit == "Update"){
        $x = 0;
        //echo $_POST['txtQuan2'];
        //echo $_POST['txtHoldProdId0'];
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_product){
            $i++;
            $quantity = $_POST['txtQuan'.$x];
            $prodStock = $_POST['txtHoldQuan'.$x];
            $prodAdjustId = $_POST['txtHoldProdId'.$x++];
            if($quantity<1){ $quantity = 1; }
            if($quantity>$prodStock){ $quantity = $prodStock; }
            while(list($key,$value)=each($each_product)){
                array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"],$i-1,1,array(array("productID"=>$prodAdjustId,"quantity"=>$quantity)));
            }       
        }

    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if(!empty($_GET['cid']) || isset($_GET['cid'])){
        $removeKey = $_GET['cid'];
        if(count($_SESSION["cart_array"])<=1){
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        }else{
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$removeKey"]);
            sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $cartTitle = "";
    $cartOutput = "";
    $cartTotal = "";
    if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
        $cartOutput="<h2 align='center'> Your shopping cart is empty </h2>";
    }else{
        $x = 0;
        $cartTitle .= '<form name="shoppingcart_form" action="shoppingcart.php" method="post" /><table width="700px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                            <th width="220" align="left">Image </th> 
                            <th width="140" align="left">Name </th> 
                            <th width="100" align="center">Quantity </th> 
                            <th width="60" align="center">Stock </th> 
                            <th width="60" align="right">Price </th> 
                            <th width="60" align="right">Total </th> 
                            <th width="90"> </th></tr>';
        #Values in here need to go into database "order_details" table
        $i = 0;

        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_product){
            $product_id = $each_product['productID'];
            $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblproduct where prod_id='$product_id' limit 1");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $prodNo = $row["prod_no"];
                $prodID = $row["prod_id"];
                $prodName = $row["prod_name"];
                $prodPrice = $row["prod_price"];
                $prodQuan = $row["prod_quan"];
            }
            $pricetotal=$prodPrice*$each_product['quantity'];
            $cartTotal= number_format($pricetotal+$cartTotal,2);
            $cartOutput .= '<tr><td><img style="border: 2px solid;" src="images/product/'.$prodNo.'.jpg" width="150" height="120" /></td> 
                <td>'.$prodName.'</td> 
                <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="txtHoldProdId'.$i.'" value="'.$prodID.'" /><input name="txtQuan'.$i.'" type="text" value="'.$each_product['quantity'].'" style="width: 40px; text-align: center" /> </td>
                <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="txtHoldQuan'.$i.'" value="'.$prodQuan.'" /> '.$prodQuan   .' pcs</td> 
                <td align="right">R '.$prodPrice.'</td> 
                <td align="right">R '.$pricetotal.'</td>
                <td align="center"> <a href="shoppingcart.php?cid='.$i++.'"><img src="images/remove_x.gif" alt="remove" /><br />Remove</a> </td></tr>';
        }
        $_SESSION['checkoutCartTotal'] = $cartTotal;
        $cartOutput .= '<tr>
                            <td colspan="3" align="right"  height="40px">Have you modified your basket? Please click here to <input class="btn_upd" type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="Update" />&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="right" style="background:#ccc; font-weight:bold"> Total: </td>
                            <td colspan="2" align="left" style="background:#ccc; font-weight:bold;">R '.$cartTotal.' </td>
                            <td style="background:#ccc; font-weight:bold"> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div style="float:right; width: 215px; margin-top: 20px;">
                    </form> 
                    </div></form>';
    }
//---------------------------------------------------
    $cTotal = $_SESSION['checkoutCartTotal'];
    @$cName = $_POST['cardName'];
    @$cNumber = $_POST['cardNum'];
    @$cAdress = $_POST['cusAddress'];
    @$cCity = $_POST['cusCity'];
    @$cEmail = $_POST['cusEmail'];
    @$cPhone = $_POST['cusPhone'];

        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_product){
            $product_id = $each_product['productID'];
            $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblproduct where prod_id='$product_id' limit 1");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $ProdID = $row["prod_id"];
                $prodPrice = $row["prod_price"];
                $ProdQuan = $row["prod_quan"];
            }
                    $sqlinsert2 = ("INSERT INTO order_details (`order_id`, `prod_id`, `cus_id`, `quantity`, `price_per_unit`) VALUES ('$order', '$ProdID', '$customer', '$ProdQuan', '$prodPrice')");
        }

    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tbl_order (`total_price`, `credit_card_number`, `fname`, `email`, `address`, `phone`, `city`,`date_ordered`) VALUES ('$cTotal','$cNumber', '$cName', '$cEmail', '$cAdress', '$cPhone', '$cCity',now())";



    if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sqlinsert)) {
        die(mysqli_error($connection));
    } 


    $newrecord = "Thank you for making your purchase!";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Great Selling Book Store</title>
<link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ddsmoothmenu.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function clearText(field)
    {
        if (field.defaultValue == field.value) field.value = '';
        else if (field.value == '') field.value = field.defaultValue;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body id="subpage">

<div id="main_wrapper">
    <div id="main_header">
        <div id="site_title"><h1><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Great Selling book Store</a></h1></div>

        <div id="header_right">
            <div id="main_search">
                <form action="products.php" method="get" name="search_form">
                  <input type="text" value="Search" name="keyword" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="clearText(this)" class="txt_field" />
                  <input type="submit" name="Search" value="" alt="Search" id="searchbutton" title="Search" class="sub_btn"  />
                </form>
            </div>
         </div> <!-- END -->
    </div> <!-- END of header -->

    <div id="main_menu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.php">Books</a></li>
            <li><a class="selected" href="shoppingcart.php">Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br style="clear: left" />
    </div> <!-- end of menu -->

    <div class="cleaner h20"></div>
    <div id="main_top"></div>
    <div id="main">

        <div id="sidebar">
            <h3>Categories</h3>
            <ul class="sidebar_menu">
                <li><a href="index.php?cat=children">Children</a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?cat=Horror">Horror</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?cat=Thriller">Thriller</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div> <!-- END of sidebar -->

        <div id="content">
        <?php echo $cartTitle; ?>
        <?php echo $cartOutput; ?>


        </div> <!-- end of content -->
        <div class="cleaner">
             <form method ="post" action="shoppingcart.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value= "true" />
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Customer Checkout</legend>
                <label>Enter your name as it is on the credit card: <input type="text" name="cardName"></label>
                <label>Card Number: <input type="text" name="cardNum"></label>
                <label>Adress: <input type="text" name="cusAddress"></label>
                <label>City: <input type="text" name="cusCity"></label>
                <label>Email: <input type="text" name="cusEmail"></label>
                <label>Please, specify your reachable phone number. YOU MAY BE GIVEN A CALL TO VERIFY AND COMPLETE THE ORDER: <input type="text" name="cusPhone"></label>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="cleaner h50"></div>
                               <td> <input type="submit" class="more" value="Checkout!"></td>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- END of main -->
                   <?php
               echo @$newrecord;
               ?>
    <div id="main_footer">   
        <div class="cleaner h40"></div>
        <center>
            Copyright © 2048 DigitalNinja
        </center>
    </div> <!-- END of footer -->   

</div>


<script type='text/javascript' src='js/logging.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why use the error surpressor? `@` remove that

Comment: Okay i removed that but it still doesn't work  @Akintunde

Comment: ```INSERT INTO `table_name` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('val1','val2'),('val3','val4');``` will insert 2 rows.

Comment: ^ pretty much.......

Comment: Or you could just move the insert inside your while loop and do two inserts. Also, your code is suseptable to SQL injection attacks. Please use prepared statements.

Comment: @SloanThrasher My html table data has some counters, so i was wondering how i put that into the sql statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert multiple rows WITHOUT repeating the "INSERT INTO dbo.Blah" part of the statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example for multiple inserts in a single query and its faster,

```
INSERT INTO example
  (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

Your Code with multiple insert option:

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_product){
    $product_id = $each_product['productID'];
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblproduct where prod_id='$product_id' limit 1");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $Prods .= '('.$order.
        ','.$row["prod_id"].
        ','. $order.
        ','.$row["prod_quan"].
        ','.$row["prod_price"].
        '),';//if text: ',"'.$row["prod_quan"].'"),';
    } 
    $Prods = rtrim($Prods, ',');// this is to remove last comma from multiple inserts
    $sqlinsert2 = ("INSERT INTO order_details (`order_id`, `prod_id`, `cus_id`, `quantity`, `price_per_unit`) VALUES $Prods"); 
    mysql_query($sqlinsert2);                       
}
```

**NOTE:** you are not running mysql_query of insert, so it's not inserting data into the database.

**WARNING:** You should use mysqli with [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: for the order_id and cus_id i have SESSION variables which are $customer = $_SESSION['id_login'];  $order = $_SESSION['id_login'];  So where will i put this lines of code in my insert statement?

Comment: first and third parameter inside while loop

Comment: Will the new while loop look like this?

Comment: `   $Prods .= '('$order ','
        .$row["prod_id"].
        ','$customer ', '
        .$row["prod_quan"].
        ','.$row["prod_price"].'),';`

Comment: see i've modified the code. and **NOTE**: you are using $order for customer id which may not be correct