# SQL - SELECT multiple rows and then INSERT them INTO another table/database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to SELECT multiple rows and then INSERT them INTO another table/database.

My current query only works with 1 result, I need it to work with for example, 100:

```
DECLARE @var INT;

SELECT
    @var = column
FROM
    database.dbo.table1

-- this will produce for example, 100 results

IF (@var IS NULL) -- which it is all 100 times
    INSERT INTO database.dbo.table2
        (column)
    VALUES
        (@var)
```

How do I do this, can this even be done?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

Comment: Please add some sample data from source

Comment: just use `INSERT INTO` with a `SELECT`: `INSERT INTO database.dbo.table2
 SELECT column FROM database.dbo.table1 WHERE somecondition`

Comment: Just insert 100 NULL values ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert multiple rows WITHOUT repeating the "INSERT INTO dbo.Blah" part of the statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want:

```
INSERT INTO database.dbo.table2(column)
    SELECT column
    FROM database.dbo.table1
    WHERE column IS NULL;
```

Comment: sounds about right....which is kinda weird...why would op want to insert just `NULL` values?

Comment: This works, thanks! I'll accept your answer when I can.

Comment: @Lamak the OP might need to generate an auto number for each record that exists at table1, without inserting data related to it. It's uncommon but it might happen D:

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use cursor for insert the data like below


DECLARE @var INT;
Declare AIX Cursor for 
SELECT  column FROM  database.dbo.table1;
Open AIX;
Fetch Next from AIX into  @var;
-- this will produce for example, 100 results
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF (@var IS  NULL) -- which it is all 100 times
    INSERT INTO database.dbo.table2
        (column)
    VALUES
            (@var)
FETCH NEXT FROM AIX 
    INTO @var;
END
CLOSE AIX;
DEALLOCATE AIX;
```

Comment: This is in direct opposition to set-based logic. There is no reason to process inserts from one table to another in a cursor. It is, in fact, an anti-pattern. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/