# inside laravel insert query i want to implement a for loop over the array to insert multiple records in one go

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, for-loop, laravel-query-builder

what i want to achieve is that inside the DB query i insert all the records in one go so that the query doesn't run many times. the following code doesn't allow me to use the for loop inside the array. kindly help.

```
if($user=="MasterDealer")
        {
            if($request['accessibleTodealers']!='' || $request['accessibleTodealers']!=null)
            {
                $memberships=explode(",",$request['accessibleTodealers']);
                $membe = array();
                $now = Carbon::now();
                DB::table('accessible_membership_logs')->insert([
                    array(
                        for ($i=0; $i <count($memberships) ; $i++){
                        array(
                            ['membership_id']=$memberships[$i],
                            ['masterdealer_id']=$dealer,
                            ['dealer_id'] = null,
                            ['user'] = 'masterdealer',
                            ['operation'] = 'Accessible',
                            ['admin_id'] = $data['id'],
                            ['created_at'] = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            ['updated_at'] = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                        )}
                    )
                ]);
                Alert::message("","Changes Updated.!","success");
                return redirect()->intended('/admin/masterDealerDetail/'.$dealer); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't do that. It's an `insert` query, it is meant to be executed as many times as the number of records that need to be inserted.

Comment: @linuxartisan but that would be a lot of stress on the DataBase, i dont want to execute the query that many times. is there any other solution?

Comment: hi you can create a table and put the object in that array, after that you 
can make **saveMany()**. it's more good and safefull.

Comment: @SteveRuben can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @MuzammilBaloch Sorry about that. As it turns out, you can add multiple records. Refer this [how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part), it may help.

Comment: @linuxartisan thanks but the answer by noufalcep did the trick for me

Comment: @linuxartisan you may want to check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#inserts  this if you want to insert multiple records in laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the loop before insert query

```
$array = array();

for ($i=0; $i <count($memberships) ; $i++){
    $array[] = array(
        'membership_id' => $memberships[$i],
        'masterdealer_id' => $dealer,
        'dealer_id' => null,
        'user' => 'masterdealer',
        'operation' => 'Accessible',
        'admin_id' => $data['id'],
        'created_at' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
}

DB::table('accessible_membership_logs')->insert($array);
```

Comment: it's showing this exception  **FatalErrorException
Assignments can only happen to writable values**

Comment: yes now it's working, what was the error? was it because we were writing the key in brackets?

Comment: Yeah. and I put `=` instead of  `=>`