# How to Bulk Insert to a SQL table from Lotusscript Agent

Tags: sql, lotusscript

I need upload over 10,000 records into a sql table from a lotusscript agent. Is there a way I can bulk load them? Excel file attachment is an option if I can do it that way. But I have to use lotusscript agent.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the answers to this question: [Insert multiple rows WITHOUT repeating the "INSERT INTO ..." part of the statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-part-of-the-stateme)

First figure out what the correct syntax for providing values to a multiple record INSERT is in the particular SQL dialect that you are working with, and then write your LotusScript code to read your data values (from Excel, or from whatever the actual source is) and produce insert them into the right places in a string containing your SQL INSERT syntax. Then submit that SQL string to your database server.