# insert into using Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am am using sql server 2005 and doing a simple insert into and getting an incorrect syntax error. I See nothing wrong with my code Can someone give me some ideas what could be wrong with it?

```
insert into inonhd 
(fpartno,fpartrev,flocation,fonhand,fcudrev)
Values
  ('CRV109','1','11','01','1'), 
  ('CRV110','0','11','01','0')
```

the error is Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? What are the datatypes for the columns?

Comment: Read [This Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462517/insert-multiple-values-using-insert-into-sql-server-2005). Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks that thread answered my question. I am using 2005 so I have to do it one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add each row in separate command.

```
insert into inonhd 
(fpartno,fpartrev,flocation,fonhand,fcudrev)
Values
('CRV109','1','11','01','1')
```

and:

```
insert into inonhd 
(fpartno,fpartrev,flocation,fonhand,fcudrev)
Values
('CRV110','0','11','01','0')
```

Comment: SQL 2008 and later supports [multiple inserts in one statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is really important to note that the syntax in the question is fine for more recent versions of SQL Server.  This is acceptable:

```
insert into inonhd(fpartno, fpartrev, flocation, fonhand, fcudrev)
    Values ('CRV109','1','11','01','1'), 
           ('CRV110','0','11','01','0');
```

If you want to do this in one statement, you can use `select . . . union all`:

```
insert into inonhd(fpartno, fpartrev, flocation, fonhand, fcudrev)
    select 'CRV109','1','11','01','1' union all
    select 'CRV110','0','11','01','0';
```

Of course, multiple inserts are another possibility.